# Commenting a region of code in C++ for Doxygen recognition

Tags: doxygen

Is there a way to add a comment block that will be understood by Doxygen to a region of code (delineated by #pragma region)?

In other words, I want to put in a comment, that Doxygen will recognize, before a group of functions:

```
/**********************//**
* \some-doxygen-tag-here ?
**************************/
#pragma region Demo Functions
.....
.....
#pragma endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doxygen module groups can help here. Group can have documentation and you can mark the beginning and the end of a group. Groups are called Modules in output documentation (not sure if this can be easily changed).

```
/** @defgroup demofuns Demo Functions
 *  Documentation of the following code block, i. e. group.
 *  @{
 */
#pragma region Demo Functions
.....
.....
#pragma endregion
/** @} */ // end of demofuns
```

See http://doxygen.org/manual/grouping.html.